# JSTL adicionando option nulo dentro de elemento select

Tags: html, angularjs, hibernate, spring, jstl

Construo uma linha `<tr>` utilizando AngularJS e JSTL, e dentro dessa linha possuo um elemento `select` em que é percorrido utlizando `<c:forEach>` sobre um enumerador para preencher a mesma quando o usuário clica para inserir uma nova linha.

```
<td><select name='atributos[{{$index}}].atributo' class='text large form-control' ng-model='atributo.tipo' ><option value='' selected><spring:message code='------------'/></option><c:forEach var='tipoAtributo' items='${EnumTipoAtributo}' varStatus='loop'><option value='${tipoAtributo.id}'><spring:message code='${tipoAtributo.label}'/></option></c:forEach></select></td>
```

Porém o select fica dessa maneira:

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Reparem no primeiro `option`, ou seja, no elemento `<option value="? object:null ?"></option>`.

Quando clico para enviar o formulário, como tem uma validação com uma anotação do Hibernate estoura o seguinte erro, invés de aparecer uma mensagem do tipo O Campo é obrigatório:

> Failed to convert property value of type java.lang.String to required type com.projeto.enums.EnumTipoAtributo for property atributos[0].tipo; nested exception is org.springframework.core.convert.ConversionFailedException: Failed to convert from type java.lang.String to type @javax.persistence.Column @javax.validation.constraints.NotNull @javax.persistence.Enumerated com.projeto.enums.EnumTipoAtributo for value ? object:null ?; nested exception is java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: No enum constant com.projeto.enums.EnumTipoAtributo.? object:null ?

Ao retornar para a página esse elemento é excluido e se deixar em branco a mensagem de validação aparece normalmente para o usuário de uma maneira que possa entende-lo, porém como posso retirar esse elemento com valor `object:null`?

Answer (score -1):

Esse trecho não aponta para o problema?

> Failed to convert property value of type java.lang.String to required
>   type com.projeto.enums.EnumTipoAtributo

Está faltando uma conversão nesse seu código, já que é esperado um `Enum` e está sendo recebido uma `String`.

Comment: Não pode e não faz sentido converter o valor para Enum que esta presente dentro desse option  sendo que o valor a ser recebido é inconsistente, ou seja, o `? object:null ?`.